# How to exclude facet wrap/grid with less than n number of observations in R

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am using ggplot to create numerous dot charts (using geom_point and facet_wrap) for two variables with multiple categories. Multiple categories have only a few points, which I cannot use,

Is there a way to set a minimum number of observations for each facet (i.e. only show plots with 10 or more observations)?

````
by_AB <- group_by(df, A, B)

by_AB%>% 
  ggplot(aes(X,Y)) +
  geom_point() +
  facet_wrap(A~B,  scales="free") + 
  geom_smooth(se = FALSE) +
  theme_bw()```
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is best to remove the small groups from your data *before* plotting. This is very easy if you do

```r
df %>% 
  group_by(A, B) %>% 
  filter(n() > 1) %>%
  ggplot(aes(X,Y)) +
  geom_point() +
  facet_wrap(A~B,  scales="free") + 
  geom_smooth(se = FALSE) +
  theme_bw()
```

Obviously, we don't have your data, so here is an example using the built-in `mtcars` data set. Suppose we want to plot `mpg` against `wt`, but facet by `carb`:

```r
library(tidyverse)

mtcars %>%
  ggplot(aes(wt, mpg)) +
  geom_point() +
  facet_wrap(.~carb)
```

[image]

Two of our facets look out of place because they only have a single point. We can simply filter these groups out *en route* to ggplot:

```r
mtcars %>%
  group_by(carb) %>%
  filter(n() > 1) %>%
  ggplot(aes(wt, mpg)) +
  geom_point() +
  facet_wrap(.~carb)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-08-25 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: Thank you, this approach is perfect ```filter(n() > 1) %>%``` is exactly what I needed.